# Undesired lines in FilledCurve (Wolfram Mathematica)

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to make a custom arrowhead with Wolfram Mathematica (v. 10.0) using function FilledCurve. The result is looking fine on the Wolfram output. When I save the picture as pdf, some undesirable vertical line appears on the left border of my arrowhead. It is visible also in the latex document where I insert my pictures.
The code is

```
px = 0.7; py = 0.14; mpx = -0.2;
pts = {{-px, py}, {mpx, 0}, {-px, -py}};
ah = Graphics[{FilledCurve[{BSplineCurve[pts], Line[{{-px, -py}, {0, 0}, {-px, py}}]}]}]
```

To see the problem you need to save the output as pdf and open it in Adobe Acrobat Reader (or insert it in latex document).

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some bag in WM.
I solves the problem just by creating the required curve "manually" from lines.
The final code (with some minor improvements) is as follows:

```
px = 0.7; py = 0.14; mpx = -0.3;
pts = {{-px, py}, {mpx, 0}, {-px, -py}};
curpts = Table[f[t], {t, 0, 1, 0.02}];
f = BSplineFunction[pts];
linpts = {{-px, -py}, {0, 0}, {-px, py}};
allpts = Join[curpts, {linpts[[-2]], linpts[[-1]]}];
ah = Graphics[{FilledCurve[Line[allpts]], Line[linpts]}]
```

[Result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdtfE.png)